# Delete all files inside a directory - skipping system protected or opened ones

Tags: java

I am writing a Java application that removes all files inside a certain directory (not the directory itself) in the end of processing.
I tried to use `FileUtils.cleanDirectory()` but it fails when there are protected or being-used files in the directory. I just want to skip those kind of files and remove others.
Please suggest a sleek solution to handle this.  Thanks!

Comment: When your program reaches such file will an exception be thrown?

Comment: Yes, `unable to delete file ...`.

Comment: One idea is to catch this exception and using your "next()" method.

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution is to just delete the files individually, the `File.delete()` function just returns false when it fails to delete the file.

```java
    File directoryPath = new File("Directory");
    File[] filesList = directoryPath.listFiles();
    for(File file : filesList) {
        try{
            file.delete();
        }catch(SecurityException e){
            //Prevented by SecurityManager
        }
    }
```

Edit: to recursively delete you can use the Files class,

```java
Path directory = Paths.get("Directory");
Files.walkFileTree(directory, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
   @Override
   public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
       try{
           Files.delete(file);
       }catch(Exception e){}
       return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
   }

   @Override
   public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
       if(!dir.equals(directory)){
           try{
               Files.delete(dir);
           }catch(Exception e){}
           return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: Does this solution remove subdirectories and files as well?  I mean recursive deletion ...

Comment: @ThunderboltEngineer No, it doesn't, I'll write up something that does work

Comment: @ThunderboltEngineer Edited it to have a recursive solution :)

Comment: I tried with your solution but it threw exception when it reached protected file. I've come up with a workaround in my application to avoid such files.  Thanks anyway!